# How would I go about incorporating a jQuery script into my Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

I have attempted to load [Typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) into a Meteor app a number of ways, but it just isn't working. I have tried simply putting it in the  of my code, and also putting it in the `client/` directory as a separate file. Nothing seems to be working, so I'm almost giving up. Maybe I'm missing something. Is there a special way to use jQuery in Meteor or something?

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="typed.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".element").typed({
            strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
            typeSpeed: 0
        });
    });
</script>
...

<span class="element"></span>
```

Comment: If someone can show me a working copy of Meteor running Typed.js that would be great, instead of just downvoting the question, as currently I'm not sure it can be done. But I'm sure it would be great to use jQuery plugins easily in Meteor projects....

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `/client/compatibility` folder? A folder that does not convert global vars into local ones

Off cause you don't need to insert jQuery itself, since meteor has it by default. Just put your `Typed.js` in the folder

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have it already as a package, here is how to install jQuery: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/jquery

You don't need a `<script>` tag to load a javascript asset with Meteor. Just put it in your client folder and Meteor will do the rest, it should be available. **However**, keep in mind that Meteor loads the files in a specific order. Most of the errors come from the fact that your code is loaded but your lib is not.

To sum it up, [read that](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp). You can, as advised by @ZuzEL, put your `typed.js`
 in `/client/compatibility`. This is a special directory loaded first.

Comment: Not just loaded first. But code here is free to rely on global variables

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for the info

Comment: I tried putting the script in `/client/compatibility` but that didn't help. It seemed to be something strange about the way meteor reads jQuery files. I was getting a 'Typed not defined' error. I'm still new to Meteor so I'm not sure if you're even supposed to be running jQuery from within Meteor..

Comment: you're not supposed to put the jquery file in your meteor project. It is already included in Meteor. Concerning the error you get, first, it is called using `typed` not `Typed`. Second, you need to make sure your DOM is loaded. To do that, wrap your code related to typed in a `Template.mytemplate.rendered` function to trigger it once the page is loaded.